# std::forward<Args> or std::forward<Args...>?

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have come across two variants of `std::forward` usage with variadic template arguments.

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... arga)
{
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);      // variant 1
    bar(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);   // variant 2

    // EDIT the above is a fixed version, the initial incorrect version was
    // bar(std::forward<Args>(args...));      // variant 1
    // bar(std::forward<Args...>(args...));   // variant 2

}
```

I have tried both variants with g++ and clang, and both appear to work equally well. No warnings produced with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

Are both variants correct? If not, why not? What does the standard have to say about it?

Comment: Even your updated question doesn't change much, variant 2 still does not work with two or more parameters. How have you actually tested your code? You need to [instantiate it with all the relevant combinations of parameters](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2695d46af54ce26) to see whether it actually works or not.

Comment: @DanielFrey apparently it wasn't adequately tested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);      // variant 1
```

This is correct.

```
bar(std::forward<Args...>(args...));   // variant 2
```

This is wrong.

If the parameter pack is empty variant 1 expands to `bar()` which is valid, but variant 2 expands to `bar(std::forward<>())` which is ill-formed because `forward` is missing its parameters.

If the pack has one element both variants expand to `bar(std::forward<T>(t))` which is valid.

If the pack has two elements variant 1 correctly expands to `bar(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2))` which is valid. But for two elements variant 2 expands to `bar(std::forward<T1, T2>(t1, t2))` which is ill-formed because `std::forward` has one template parameter and one function parameter.

So in all cases variant 1 works, but variant 2 is only valid for the case of a parameter pack with one element (and if you only care about a single template argument you shouldn't be using a variadic template at all!)

Basically a pack expansion should be `PATTERN...` where pattern is the thing you want to be repeated for each element in the pack. Since you want to call `std::forward<T>(t)` for each element, the PATTERN should be `std::forward<Args>(args)` and so the full pack expansion is that followed by `...` (and not something with the `...` *inside* the PATTERN, which results in two separate pack expansions, one of the types in `Args` and one of the variables in `args`).

Comment: Sorry about the ellipsis confusion everyone.

Comment: Hmm, if the pack is empty, doesn't the second one expand to `std::forward<>()`?

Comment: @DanielFrey `std::forward<Args...>(args)...` expands to nothing. `std::forward<Args...>(args...)` expands to `std::forward<>()`.

Comment: @T.C. yes, you're right, edited -- it's still ill-formed though.